# Non-ascii characters in RewriteRule :alpha:

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, regex

I have `RewriteRule ^([[:alpha:]]+)$ do-something.php?parameter=$1` and it works for URLs like `.../Virtanen`. For `.../Mähönen` I can use `([ÄÖäö[:alpha:]]+`, but that of course fails for, say, `.../Vadén`. How to make `:alpha:` interpreted as Unicode characters?

This has been asked several times, but no answer I found works.

I use Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 3):

`mod_rewrite` documentation at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html#regex says:

> mod_rewrite uses the Perl Compatible Regular Expression vocabulary. In this document, we do not attempt to provide a detailed reference to regular expressions. For that, we recommend the PCRE man pages, the Perl regular expression man page, and Mastering Regular Expressions, by Jeffrey Friedl.

In "PCRE" you have the liberty to match through Unicode properties, see https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops#Properties-accessible-through-%5Cp%7B%7D-and-%5CP%7B%7D

Which means, if really properly implemented by `mod_rewrite` that `\p{Block: Latin_1}` in your expression would match any character in the "Latin 1 Supplement" block, which is the case for characters `ÄÖäö`.

There are of course other ways to select, depending on expected input. You have even `\p{General_Category: Letter}` for any character that is defined as a "letter" in the Unicode database.

> This has been asked several times, but no answer I found works.

When asking, it could help to specify, even quickly, what you tried already that doesn't work. That allows to avoid anyone repeating something you already know not to work. I did not try the above, so maybe it doesn't work (but should based on documentation) or maybe you tried already?

Comment: Unfortunately at least `RewriteRule ^\p{Block: Latin_1}$ ...`, `RewriteRule ^\p\{Block: Latin_1\}$ ...`and `RewriteRule ^\\p\{Block: Latin_1\}$ ...` all give just an internal server error.

I try to re-read some pages and modify question to that it tells what I have already tried.

Comment: Any details on the internal server error? Did you crank up Apache logs and specifically mod_rewrite logs? I would try also without the space after `:`. And if anything works it would be the first form, the other ones are other things. Maybe do check also with which PCRE library your Apache was compiled with, and hence what it supports exactly. Unfortunately "Perl Compatible Regular Expression" can mean a lot of different things, with various level of support. And it moved during the years of course, so Apache documentation here is a little lacking in details.

Comment: First I got `RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters` and after removing the space after colon, `RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '^\\p{General_Category:Letter}$`. This is version 2.4.53 on Debian 11.

Comment: "I would try also without the space after `:`" - the _space_ would certainly cause an error in Apache config files (since the _space_ is the argument delimiter). Either remove it as suggested, or enclose the entire argument in double quotes. See also: https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: `^\\p{General_Category:Letter}$` - You shouldn't escape the backslash.

Comment: MrWhite, I do have `RewriteRule "^\p{General_Category: Letter}$" ..` but still I get `cannot compile regular expression '^\\p{General_Category: Letter}$'`.

Comment: @JoriMäntysalo There are certainly differences between "Perl regex" and PCRE. As noted in the article I linked to above, "PCRE is far less flexible in what it allows for the `\p` tokens, despite its name “Perl-compatible”". Try `\p{Latin}` and the other "unicode blocks" as listed in that article.

Comment: Progress! `\p{Latin}` works, for example `\p{Latin_1}` does not. But it seems that `Latin` does not detect `ä` or `ö`. Anyways, I guess I can proceed with this to see if I found a solution.

Comment: "Progress! \p{Latin} works, for example \p{Latin_1} does not. " `\p` by default is just for Unicode scripts, and `Latin` is a script but `Latin_1` is not a script, it is describing a Unicode block (list of characters), hence my initial answer using `\p{Block:Latin_1}` . If `\p{Block:X}` is not matching anything maybe that form is not handled in PCRE, and then from the page of @MrWhite comment, `\p{InLatin-1_Supplement}` should be used as equivalent.

Comment: "But it seems that Latin does not detect ä or ö": Script=Latin should match `ä` aka U+0101 character per https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=[:Script=Latin:]; do remember however that non ASCII characters are encoded in URLs (percent encoding of the Unicode codepoint in UTF8), so make sure the mod_rewrite part sees the decoded values (I am not sure on this point, I would have to search).

Comment: `\p{InLatin-1_Supplement}` gives "cannot compile regular expression".

If `ä` should match, then maybe this is about percent encoding. OTOH plain `ä` in a `RewriteRule` works. Hmm... this seems to be hard one.

Comment: The `RewriteRule` _pattern_ (as you are using here) matches against the %-decoded URL-path, so this should not be a percent encoding issue. (As you say, you are able to match a  "plain `ä`"). @JoriMäntysalo